# I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I believe that this error has something to do with the fact that I am not running my JSON in a thread. Here is my code below how can I fix this? Do I need to put this into a runnable, if so how do I do that? I am relativitly new to the idea of threads so please help me out?

```
 private void JsonRequestMethod() {
            mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
            //intitalize Volley Singleton request key
            mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
            //2 types of requests an Array request and an Object Request
            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_API, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    listblogs.clear(); // here you clear the old data
                    listblogs=parseJSONResponse(response);
                    mAdapterDashBoard.setBloglist(listblogs);

                    System.out.println("it worked!!!");
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
            mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
private ArrayList<Blogs> parseJSONResponse(JSONArray response) {
    if (!response.equals("")) {
        ArrayList<Blogs> blogsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = currentQuestions.getString("text");
                String points = currentQuestions.getString("points");
                String ID=currentQuestions.getString("id");
                String studentId = currentQuestions.getString("studentId");
                String DateCreated=currentQuestions.getString("created");
                long time=Long.parseLong(DateCreated.trim());
                data.append(text + "\n" + points + "\n");
                System.out.println(data);
                Blogs blogs = new Blogs();
                blogs.setId(ID);
                blogs.setMstudentId(studentId);
                blogs.setMtext(text);
                blogs.setPoints(points);
                //The dateCreated was off by 1 hour so 3600000 ms where added=1hour, (UPDATE)
                blogs.setDateCreated(getTimeAgo(time));
                System.out.println(time+"time");


                listblogs.add(blogs);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listblogs;
}
```

Comment: This is not an **error**. Not even a **warning**. It's just a **log** message.

Comment: what about this? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 46K, 42% free 59054K/100860K, paused 16ms, total 16ms

Comment: My app is pausing between switching screens in a sliding tab layout and these are the only two log messages between screens so one has to be responsible

Comment: But the app does NOT stop or crashes. These are micro-lags due to unoptimized code execution. Either yours or system routines (or other apps running in the background). Really. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to optimize it then?

Comment: If it's your code, it will be probably optimized on compiling (or you can try to discove some optimization techniques). If it's not, there's nothing you can do. Nothing to worry, as I said. 16 milliseconds is nothing. You can never notice such a small lag.

Comment: Use method tracing in Android Studio to determine exactly where you are spending your time. 33 frames is ~500 milliseconds, so you should be able to get a decent idea where in your code your are spending that half-second.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing JSON parsing in the UI thread. Use Gson to convert it to ArrayList`new Gson.fromJson(yourObject, class);` convert your response to POJO [www.jsonschema2pojo.org/](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)